# NextAuth MongoDB Adapter breaking login

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

I have run into an issue where I added an adapter to the NextAuth which has created an issue logging in. The route.js is

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      id: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "test@example.com",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const email = credentials?.email;
        const password = credentials?.password;

        mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        const passwordOk =
          user && bcryptjs.compareSync(password, user.password);

        if (passwordOk) {
          return user;
        }

        // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

When I keep it as is, I can log in with google, but I cannot log in with credentials. When I add

```
    session: {
    strategy: "jwt"
  },
```

it allows me to log in with credentials, but not with my google accounts. The mongoDB adapter was taken from the next-auth website so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.